# tsCV h-step-ahead when h>1

Tags: r, time-series

[schematic 4-step-ahead forecasts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvqJm.png)

According to the illustration above, I'd expect the time period of the first CV error (first non-NA values) in the column h=4 to be period 10, right? The result below shows that all first CV errors start at period 7. Why is this so?

```
> data <- ts(rnorm(n = 50, mean = 10, sd = 5))
> tsCV(data, forecastfunction = splinef, h = 4, initial = 6) %>% head(12)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 12 
Frequency = 1 
          h=1         h=2        h=3       h=4
 1         NA          NA         NA        NA
 2         NA          NA         NA        NA
 3         NA          NA         NA        NA
 4         NA          NA         NA        NA
 5         NA          NA         NA        NA
 6         NA          NA         NA        NA
 7 -0.6898367  1.94707898 -0.4241705 2.6114473
 8  2.2835535 -0.03213156  3.0590506 2.9266469
 9 -1.0397064  1.90081726  1.6177550 4.7870414
10  2.3104741  2.08295460  5.3077838 5.1881762
11  1.2481952  4.36896765  4.1453033 3.9093216
12  3.9553215  3.68404796  3.4004571 0.4572387
```

Image source: https://otexts.com/fpp2/accuracy.html, Rob J Hyndman

Answer (score 0):

From the help file for `forecast::tsCV`:

> ## Value
>
> Numerical time series object containing the forecast errors as a vector (if h=1) and a matrix otherwise. The time index corresponds to the last period of the training data. The columns correspond to the forecast horizons.

So the cell at time=7 and h=4 gives forecasts for time 11.